# Run a command in bitbake recipe as if on live system

Tags: yocto, openembedded, bitbake

Is it possible to run a command in a recipe as if it were run on the live system? If so, how? I want to import my key(s) into [gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/) before the image is created so I don't have to log onto the system after formatting the SD card.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution that involves specifying a post install script that runs when do_rootfs is called. All I added to my recipe which installs my public key on the system is below:

```
pkg_postinst_${PN}() {
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "$D" ]; then
    OPT="--homedir $D/home/root/.gnupg"
else
    OPT=""
fi

gpg $OPT --import ${D}${datadir}/mykey.gpg
}
```

Comment: Why not creating its own package for it?

Comment: I have. I just posted the relevant information though.

Comment: I want to execute one shell script in a yocto recipe after every bitbake command. Will you please share your recipe?